# Overloading $this->layout()-> in a view file

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to modify an array of options in ZF2 that needs to be used in my layout. In this particular case it's a filename.

When I do it as as string, I have no problems.

```
<?php $this->layout()->javaScripts = "assets/js/js-file.js"; ?>
```

When I try to append it to an array:

```
<?php $this->layout()->javaScripts[] = "assets/js/js-file.js"; ?>
```

Zend screams:

```
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Zend\View\Model\ViewModel::$javaScripts has no effect in
```

What's the proper way to do this? Or if there is no way to do this, why shouldn't I?

I've tried to RTM with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Please look at [HeadScripts](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.head-script.html)

javaScripts isn't public property - it realized with 'magic' methods

or try this

```
<?php 
$this->layout()->javaScripts = array();
$this->layout()->javaScripts[] = "assets/js/js-file.js";
```

or the same

```
<?php 
$this->layout()->javaScripts = array("assets/js/js-file.js");
```

Comment: say it were $zebraScripts, would I need to do the same thing? do you know how/where this is realized in the source? @Vasil Vanchuck

Comment: that works of course, but it dosent let me set an options array at the controller level and the modify it at the view level which is what I'm trying to do

Comment: by modify it, i mean add to my options

Comment: Why? you just should assign array before adding elements to it - first write = array() and only late push there elements - i'm about first variant of code

Comment: <?php 
$this->layout()->javaScripts = array();
$this->layout()->javaScripts[] = "assets/js/js-file.js";

Comment: class Controller extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->layout()->javaScripts = array();
    }
} /* Can't use it with this */. Still overloaded.

Comment: I see. Let's try the other way - which instance of is returning by layout()? If it's your class - you can just declare public property javaScripts. Can you?

Comment: +1 for HeadScriptHelper. You could also look at [InlineScript Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.inline-script.html) as it is a good practice to put scripts at the end of your html